# How to disable key repeat in vim?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, normal-mode, repeated-commands

I am currently try to break inefficient habits, and one bad habit is to keep a button pressed, e.g. keep pressing <kbd>j</kbd> to move down approximately 10 lines instead of moving exactly 10 lines down with `10j`, or moving across words with <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> instead of doing wordwide movements with <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>.

In order to make me realize that I am doing something inefficient, I have currently disabled key repeat on my Ubuntu, yet this affects all key-presses in all application. And while this is a smell in most application, it has its uses for some of them; so I am wondering:

How to disable key repeat in vimrc?

Answer (score 6):

This would be not a smart solution, because the `hjkl` are particularly useful if you are moving 1-2 characters up and down.

Nevertheless, if you want to disable repetition of `j` for example use this mapping:

```
nnoremap jj <nop>
```

You also may have to set `timeoutlen` to a low value (`set timeoutlen=50`)

Comment: If I want to move the cursor for two characters, I can just use `2l`, that's the whole point of the question to use the amount modifier. And I still would be able two press j twice in a short succession. I only want the repeat to stop when keeping the button pressed down.

Comment: even with a low setting for `timeoutlen`, using `j` for down movement is too slow if you implement this solution.